# Monads and Actors

Tags: concurrency, f#, actor, monads, system.reactive

I've been trying to find anything that discusses when you should favor the use of monads over actors (in concurrency scenarios), but I've found nothing. In particular, I'm wondering about the use of the Reactive Extensions (LINQ to Events) vs. F#'s MailboxProcessor. Please give examples in addition to any philosophical reasoning you might have.

**Update**
For better context, the Reactive Extensions implement the continuation monad in the form of IObservable/IObserver. I'm not necessarily saying I have to use F#, just that F# has a concrete "actor model" available in a .NET language in the form of MailboxProcessor<'T>.

What I'm trying to understand is when to use a monad (in this case a continuation monad) vs. an actor model for concurrency purposes. Where the monad (as I understand it) doesn't introduce state, the actor has its own internal state that is modified as necessary to provide protected access.

I've seen a number of examples of using both: Rx and node.js (CPS, not really the continuation monad) vs. F#'s MailboxProcessor and Scala's Akka framework. I just don't know why you would choose one over the other.

Comment: This will probably be completely useless to you since I don't know f# and don't really understand where your question is coming from, but I wrote an actor model implementation in haskell which makes use of monad stack (an actor computation is a Reader/IO monad): http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/simple-actors/0.1.0/doc/html/Control-Concurrent-Actors.html

Comment: [Phil Trelford](http://twitter.com/ptrelford) has also created an implementation of [Rx using actors](http://minirx.codeplex.com/), so it would appear that, depending on what you are doing, you could implement actors using monads or monads using actors.

Comment: Another "might not be of any use to you" piece. I've once been pointed out that the primary purpose of Rx isn't to introduce concurrency but to tackle it. While one may regard F# agent's as an appropriate way to introduce concurrency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to respond to my own question and say you should use both. This is based on [Don Syme's post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2010/02/15/async-and-parallel-design-patterns-in-f-part-3-agents.aspx). A MbP uses the Async computation to do its work, and the Async is a thread-aware continuation monad. Looks like you can use it by itself for some uses, but the MbP definitely requires it.

<s>I don't really like this answer, and I'd be happy for someone to respond with a better explanation of when to use each.</s>

**Updated:**

See [MiniRx](http://minirx.codeplex.com/), which is now apart of [FSharpx](http://github.com/fsharp/fsharpx), for an implementation of an Rx-style monad implemented using `MailboxProcessor`. As `MailboxProcessor` is itself implemented using the `async` monad, these pieced to indeed work together. They are just different means of abstraction.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure that the question makes sense as phrased - there are many different monads (e.g. the identity monad, the list monad, the option monad, ...), most of which have nothing to do with concurrency.  Furthermore, it would be helpful to know more about the particular scenario that you're dealing with - "concurrency" is a bit of a nebulous topic.  Depending on what you're trying to achieve, F#'s `async` workflows (which are built on the `Async` monad) might be your best bet.

If you're using F#, I'd recommend against using LINQ-to-anything directly, since those libraries have a very alien feel when accessed via F#.  You could, however, create pleasant F# wrappers (such as the existing `Seq` and `Observable` modules).  Additionally, for monadic types, you could create a computation expression builder (e.g. you could create a builder using the Reactive Extensions which would enable you to use computation expressions to build and compose `IObservable`s).

Comment: I'm familiar with the options. I'm curious as to why and when you should choose one over the other. This may be a preference thing, but I thought I would try to get a better understanding.

For some F# to Rx wrappers, check out my bitbucket repo: http://bitbucket.org/riles01/fsharp.reactive

Comment: It seems like you are comparing one that has a backing store that can be filled independently of the computation(MbP), against one that doesn't (Seq/Observable). These are very different situations and would be application specific.

Answer (score 1):

Please excuse my newbie-ness as I'm just learning F#.

I'm intrigued to see the use of RX in place of a MailboxProcessor, if you have any links to relevant materials.

With my limited understanding; I would choose MbP's in my own code as events are a bit messy to set up in F# (from what I can take from this article: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233189.aspx)). And you need events for RX to hook into right?

Where as with a MbP all I need is a discriminated union of messages, a list of functions I wish to be executed when a given message is received. And the mail box processor that handles this.

This all looks pretty neat in the code. I can bunch my MbP's together in a module then my "object" module looks like

- Record
- Message DU
- Wrapper with some getters and setters that post data to the MbP

For me this looks a lot neater than it would If I wrote my code with events as described in that MSDN article I linked to.

Though I am just an F# junior so I may be a miles off with my reckoning and it is a look-&-feel thing rather than a suitability-for-purpose choice (as I'm not qualified to make that call, yet)

Comment: Depending on how you expose your events, you can do as little as declaring an event and returning it as an IObservable, with the Trigger() method called inside the Subscribe method, so I don't think events are that bad. MbP's have their own req's.

Comment: @jdoig What you described is more or less the standard pattern for MbP usage.  There are various examples here: http://fssnip.net/tags/Agent

Comment: Note that you can even generate observables from the various built-in static methods. I wouldn't think you'd ever need to setup any events at all and the code would be more idiomatic/functional Rx.

Answer (score 1):

Would you accept answers from the Scala world?

If you seek "a purely functional alternative to actor model" then please see this great post from Paul Chiusano's blog

[pchiusano.blogspot.ro/2010/01/actors-are-not-good-concurrency-model.html](http://pchiusano.blogspot.ro/2010/01/actors-are-not-good-concurrency-model.html)
(archived here: http://archive.is/NxNLc)

and some references below:

http://noelwelsh.com/programming/2013/03/04/why-i-dont-like-akka-actors/

> Actors do not Compose
> Akka’s Actors are not Usefully Typed
> The type system is the reason we use Scala.

https://opencredo.com/akka-typed/

> Unfortunately, the current API suffers from a few drawbacks, which are to a good degree associated with the lack of type safety

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/typed.html

> Status of this Project and Relation to Akka Actors
> Akka Typed is the result of many years of research and previous attempts (including Typed Channels in the 2.2.x series) and it is on its way to stabilization, but maturing such a profound change to the core concept of Akka will take a long time
>
> A side-effect of this is that behaviors can now be tested in isolation without having to be packaged into an Actor, tests can run fully synchronously without having to worry about timeouts and spurious failures. Another side-effect is that behaviors can nicely be composed and decorated

[Composable application architecture with reasonably priced monads](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M258zVn4m2M&feature=youtu.be&t=1598)

- https://youtu.be/M258zVn4m2M?t=1955
- https://youtu.be/M258zVn4m2M?t=1986

The concept of "function passing style" from Heather Miller might be key to a distributed functional programming model.

[SF Scala: Heather Miller, Function-Passing Style, A New Model for Distributed Programming](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4obTnLVXQWY)

*Update 12/2018* : now we can use `Aecor` which provide the means to:

- implement business domain logic with a functional `programming model` and
- use an `Akka` based `runtime`

> *"behaviors belong to the domain layer and runtime is out there in the infrastructure layer."*

Source: https://pavkin.ru/aecor-part-3/, http://aecor.io